# How to change keyboard.key background when it's pressed?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

How do I change keyboard.key background in onPress method when key is pressed and change it again when key is released? If you need any part of my code, please ask. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Find or add the applicable event methods and modify the view to which they refer.  Keyboards aren't necessarily simple code, and sometimes do their own matching of touch coordinates to views rather than use the system's, so how this will need to be done is *heavily* dependent on how your implementation handles touches.

Comment: Do you mean background of a button on a software keyboard?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've searched for something but I couldn't find anything. @SergiiRudchenko Yes, background of a single button in keyboard.

Comment: Can you post the code for the onPress() method?

Comment: @AndrewOrobator onPress() method is empty for now..because of that I asked a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're writing a keyboard app, you will probably have to override `onTouch(MotionEvent)`. In this method, you should call super.onTouch(MotionEvent), then implement your background changes based on the return type of MotionEvent.getAction(). If it's ACTION_UP or ACTION_CANCEL, put the background in a normal state. If it's ACTION_DOWN, put the background in a pressed state.